# In JSDoc, how can I document an object that takes both optional named properties of specific types and unknown properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

In my JavaScript module I have defined an object type in JSDoc that I use in a function:

```
//@ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {number} age
 * @property {string} name
 */

/**
 * Birthday wishes to person
 * @param {Person} person
 */
function birthdayWish(person) {
    return 'Happy birthday number'+person.age+', '+person.name;
}
```

When I call this function I want to be able to have additional properties not cause an error:

```js
birthdayWish({'name':'Sam', 'age':35, 'occupation':'teacher'})
// Want this to work but it produces a TypeScript error
```

But I do want the named properties to be forced to follow the type:

```js
birthdayWish({'name':'Joe', 'age':'hmm', 'occupation':'lawyer'})
// Want this to be an error because age is the wrong type
```

Is there a way to define Person that would allow this?

I tried changing the typedef to:

```
 /**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, *>} Person
 * @property {number} age
 * @property {string} name
 */
```

But with this definition, neither of the birthday calls will flag an error because the age and name type restrictions are ignored.

Comment: Why not use TypeScript to define types instead of JSDoc?

Comment: TypeScript brings a bunch of extra overhead that I don't want to deal with in this pure JS module.

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured this out and it turns out to be possible to simply define the TypeScript type suggested by @xgqfrms within the JSDoc:

```js
//@ts-check

/** @typedef {{name:string, age:number, [id:string]:any}} Person */

/**
 * Say happy birthday
 * @param {Person} person
 * @returns {string}
 */
function birthday(person) {
    return 'Happy birthday '+person.age+' to '+person.name;
}

// OK
birthday({name:'John', age:25});
 
// OK
birthday({name:'John', age:25, occupation:'miner'});

// Correctly flags an error in VS code for use of wrong age type
birthday({name:'John', age:'X', occupation:'miner'});
```

One of the subtleties of TypeScript syntax is that if you instead define the Person without the [id:string]:any part, i.e.,

```js
//@ts-check

/** @typedef {{name:string, age:number}} Person */
```

then you can still add extra properties in the object passed to the birthday function but only if the object is defined as a named object and not defined anonymously in the function call, i.e.,:

```js
// OK
let JohnObj = {name:'John', age:25, occupation:'miner'}
birthday(JohnObj); 

// Error
birthday({name:'John', age:25, occupation:'miner'});
```

Recommended reading: TypeScript's [JSDoc support](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#typedef-callback-and-param)

Answer (score 1):

### I think it's hard to do, or impossible.

> What you want is easily achieved in TypeScript.

```
type PersonObject = {
  age: number;
  name: string;
  optional?: string;
  // dynamic props ✅
  [key: string]: any;
}

/*

type PersonObject = {
  [key: string]: any;
  age: number;
  name: string;
}

*/

const person1:PersonObject = {'name':'xgqfrms', 'age': 18, 'emoji': ''}
const person2:PersonObject = {'name':'xgqfrms', 'age': 18, 'xyz': 'ufo'}
const person3:PersonObject = {'name':'xgqfrms', 'age': '❌'}
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

### not a perfect solution

If you could know all the keys in the object, but some keys are optional. Just use a type definition with `optional property`.

If not, why not use TypeScript or give up using any type checking?

```js
//@ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {number} age
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {string} [occupation]
 */

/**
 * Birthday wishes to period
 * @param {Person} person
 */
function birthdayWish(person) {
  return 'Happy birthday number'+person.age+', '+person.name;
}

birthdayWish({'name':'Sam', 'age':35, 'occupation':'teacher'})

birthdayWish({'name':'Joe', 'age':'hmm', 'occupation':'lawyer'})
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

### refs

https://jsdoc.app/tags-property.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to restrict the users of the module to specific named properties like 'occupation', I just want to be able to control the types of a named subset of the properties in the object being passed to the function. What I'm looking for is more like an interface in TypeScript I believe.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the TypeScript version and the thoughts on the JSDoc version. To answer the question of why, I am working on a widget toolkit (long story) and I want the constructor of each widget class to take an object arg of properties to set on the widget that obey the correct types (e.g. the text property of a Label should always be a string) but allow the user to define additional user-defined properties by including those properties in the passed object. The user defined properties can be added to the object outside of the constructor but there's a convenience to doing it inside.

Comment: As far as JS vs TS goes, I want the lib to be compatible with both and JSDoc annotations are one way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

should be something like this.

the brackets around the property name indicate `optional`

```js
//@ts-check

/**
 * @typedef {Object} Person
 * @property {number} age
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {Object.<string, string>} [additionalProperties] // this takes any key/value pair with no constraints
 * @property {Object.<string|number, string>} [additionalProperties] // you can also add constraints on the key with types
 * @property {Object.<string, number>} [additionalProperties] // you can also add constraints on the value with types
 */
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for my intended use case: the caller rather than the module can define whatever properties they want in addition to the known ones. I just want to use JSDoc to hint to the type checker that the known properties have to be a certain type.